# How to rewrite URL using Codeigniter route or htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have created a **Home** page controller with a **Page** method so that it can load inner page views. So I simply pass the **Page name** as an argument to **Page** method and it loads that specific view.

```
E.g. 
http://www.mywebsite.com/home/page/copyright
```

So here 
1. **home** is controller
2. **page** is method
3. **copyright** is the parameter passed to page() method

So the home age loads simply using this URL

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/home/
```

and inner pages load using this url pattern

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/home/page/copyright
```

Now I want to load inner pages so that suppose I use this URL

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/copyright
```

it should load the page from

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/home/page/copyright
```

How can I do this using Codeigniter Route method or by using .htaccess file ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your application/config/routes.php :

```
$route['copyright'] = 'home/page/copyright';
```

Even better:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/page/$1';
```

So if you navigate to http://www.domain.com/copyright it routes to home/page/copyright
If you navifate to http://www.domains.com/anything it routes to home/page/anything

**EDIT to catch any route**

Although in this case you have to "catch" pages that you don t route like:

```
function page($section = ''){

 switch($section){
  case 'contact':  
   //display contact form
  break;

  case 'copyright':
  //display copyright
  break;

  default:
  //404 error
  break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, however, OP, I wouldn't do this for entire site, just special pages as that 1). defeats the MVC and 2). sure would fill up your routes.php file and be a bear to maintain.

Comment: worked nicely, I am OK with this method as my website has very few fixed pages. Wonder if there are so many pages then how it should be incorporated ?